# My three.js script is not running on a-frame

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I'm trying to make a raycaster only function when an entity is visible. I was told to try to write a script in order for this to work, so I went ahead and did such. 
All entities and child entities, I have interactable through click and have most of my events triggered through click, which make certain entities turn invisible as such:

```
<script id="city" type="text/html">
      <a-entity class="city"
        geometry="primitive: plane; height: 0.2; width: 0.5"
        data-raycastable
        material="color: black"
        text="value: ${city_name}; color: white; align: center; wrapCount: 10; font: exo2bold"
        event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.5 1.5 1"
        event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1"
        event-set__1="_event: click; _target: #image-360; _delay: 300; material.src: ${src}"
        event-set__2="_event: click; _target: #models; _delay: 300; visible: false"
        event-set__3="_event: click; _target: #cities; _delay: 300; visible: true"
        event-set__4="_event: click; _target: #show_button; _delay: 300; visible: true"
        event-set__5="_event: click; _target: ${map}; _delay: 300; visible: true"
        proxy-event="event: click; to: #image-360; as: fade"
        sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"></a-entity>
    </script>
```

The data-raycastable parameter you see here is running of this here script:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('data-raycastable', {
      init: function () {
        var self = this;
        var el = this.el;
        var data = this.data;

        this.eventHandlerFn = function () {
          if (el.object3D.visible = true){
          el.setAttribute('data-raycastable', '');
          }
          else {
            el.removeAttribute('data-raycastable')
          }
        }

        update: function() {

          el.addEventListener('click', this.eventHandlerFn);
          } 
          }
        }
      })
```

Now, I'm wondering why this script of mine doesn't work. I followed the A-frame documentation closely in an attempt to make it work, but it doesnt. The cursor button looks like this:

```
<a-entity id="camera" camera look-controls>
    <a-cursor
      id="cursor"
      material="color: black; shader: flat"
      position="0 0 -4.5"       
      geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.15; radiusOuter: 0.2"
      animation__click="property: scale; startEvents: click; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; dur: 150"
      animation__fusing="property: fusing; startEvents: fusing; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1500"
      event-set__mouseenter="_event: mouseenter; color: springgreen"
      event-set__mouseleave="_event: mouseleave; color: black"
      raycaster="objects: [data-raycastable], .link, .model">
    </a-cursor>        
  </a-entity>
```

Can someone please steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Share a link to a full runnable example that people can look at. Glitch will do https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: So far you’re putting your HTML in a script tag while it should be in the <body>. Your entities should be in the <a-scene> tag. Use glitch as a starting point: https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/amusing-nitrogen?path=MiddleEast_Map2.html:138:29 here you go good sir

Comment: Thanks. There’s a lot of stuff going on there (multiple html files). Hard to see the intent and where to look at. So far you have JS embedded in HTML with no script tags, multiple <a-assets> where it should be only one, templates using script tags doesn’t seem correct... I recommend starting with a working scene and keep it simple so people can help you... https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Hey there man, sorry for being a burden, but I was appending it while you were looking at it most likely. If you can look one more time at this link, https://glitch.com/edit/#!/amusing-nitrogen?path=pictureGallery_middleEast.html:20:12, that would be very helpful. I am very lost as to how to make my not visible components not clickable/raycastable. I am also very new to this

Comment: Sorry, not time to go through such a big project. The experience doesn’t render so hard to identify expected behavior and fix if. Reduce the code to a minimum working set that illustrates your problem. Your project has tons of images, components, not well formed templates not relevant to the question making very hard for someone to help.

Comment: I shortened the code a good deal into a new file. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/amusing-nitrogen?path=short_code.html:26:16
Hopefully, it is a lot more clearer for you. The bulk of the code is just me making multiple entities. I just don't know how to make a script that will be able to turn objects with "visible: false" into not being able to be raycasted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your component is trying to accomplish, so far it has a syntax error (missing comma after schema) and the `el` reference is not valid. Corrected code:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('data-raycastable', {         
          schema: {
            event: {type: 'boolean', default: true}  
          },
          init: function () {
            var el = this.el;
            el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                if (el.object3D.visible = false) {
                  el.classList.remove('raycastable');
                }
                else if (el.object3D.visible = true) {
                  el.classList.add('raycastable');
                }
            })
          }  
        });
```

Use classes instead of data attributes for raycastability. Corrected glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aquatic-aftershave

Comment: Hey man, thank you so much for checking out my code. I tried the corrected glitch and it seems that the invisible entities are still raycastable

Comment: Call `document.querySelector('[raycaster]').components.raycaster.refreshObjects();`     . I corrected the glitch

Comment: I don't know if I did something inherently wrong in the code, but I just ran it again with the correction, and it still fails to not raycast invisible items

Comment: Code is complex and you never described what the expected behavior is. I just see buttons that change the displayed panorama when clicked. I'm not sure what elements are you expecting to toggle visibility and raycastability. That's logic that has to go in the click handler above.

Comment: One example is I click on the Levant map in front of me and the model to the left becomes invisible. How would I make this example work? If i know how this one work, I think I should be able to carry the logic over for my other scenarios

Comment: There are no models in the glitch you provided. You have to select the appropriate entities in the click handler above and check for visibility and toggle the raycastable class accordingly `el.classList.remove('raycastable');` and finally call `document.querySelector('[raycaster]').components.raycaster.refreshObjects();`

Comment: You commented out the model and show button in the code of yours. I am honestly so sorry for being such a bother. This problem has been bothering me for about a week now and I have no one to reach out to

Comment: I commented to see if it made any difference and put them back. No model is shown. You can see here: https://aquatic-aftershave.glitch.me/

Comment: I still recommend distillate your problem to the minimum possible example you can. A cube and a cursor will do. If all moving parts and intent are visible it will be much easier to help you. You can later port back the solution to your code base.

Comment: You should see it if you move your cursor 90deg to the left. Its directly to the left of you. The show button is directly on the right

Comment: It's still complicated to understand what you are trying to accomplish. There's conflicting logic like the `event-set__2="_event: click; _target: #model; _delay: 300; visible: true"` that sets the model visibility to true on click and the click handler above is not going to toggle raycastability as you expect. If you can distillate your code to a minimum and state clearly the expected behavior vs. what you get I'm happy to look at it again.